# Query using subqueries in where statement

Tags: sql, subquery

I have a query with subqueries in the where statement which works fine but I need to improve on it but I am not sure of the best way to go about this.

Basically I am getting **last** years results for students in **this** years classes. The code below works fine for classcode '10DRADRA1' but there are many more classes and I want the query to iterate through all classes for 2017 Semester 1. I need to have the classcode included as one of the output fields also. So the query will start with the first class and give all the results for that class, then do the same for the next class in the subquery. I am not sure how to include the classcode in the select statement next to all the results from the previous year.

Note that students may do a number of classes this year so there may be some repetition of the results from the previous year. Every class they do this year should include the students name and their results from the previous year. I hardcoded '10DRADRA1' in just to get things working, if I remove it it provides all students in the school only once, while I want each class they are in once and the same results for every class they are in.

Also not that vStudentReportsSemesterResults is a view that holds all results,              StudentClasses is a table which holds the class codes a student is doing and SubjectClasses is a table holding the codes for all classes in the school

Is anyone able to advise on the best way of doing this? Here is my current code.

```
SELECT      vStudentReportsSemesterResults.StudentID, 
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessResultsResult, 
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2, 
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.FileSemester, 
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.FileYear,
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.ClassLearningAreaCode, 
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessmentCode, 
            vStudentReportsSemesterResults.StudentNameInternal

FROM        vStudentReportsSemesterResults 

WHERE      vStudentReportsSemesterResults.StudentID in 
            (
            select StudentClasses.ID from StudentClasses
            where StudentClasses.filesemester = 1 and 
            StudentClasses.fileyear = 2017 and 
            StudentClasses.classcode in 
                (
                select SubjectClasses.ClassCode from SubjectClasses
                where SubjectClasses.FileYear = 2017 and 
                SubjectClasses.FileSemester = 1 and 
                SubjectClasses.FileType = 'A' and 
                SubjectClasses.ClassCampus = 'S' and 
                SubjectClasses.ClassCode like '10DRADRA1'
                )
            )
            and (vStudentReportsSemesterResults.ClassLearningAreaCode = 'ENG'     OR
             vStudentReportsSemesterResults.ClassLearningAreaCode = 'MAT' OR
             vStudentReportsSemesterResults.ClassLearningAreaCode = 'SCI') AND 
             (vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'Grade' OR 
             vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 = 'Level') AND 
             (vStudentReportsSemesterResults.AssessResultsResult <> '') AND 
             (vStudentReportsSemesterResults.FileYear = 2016) AND 
             (vStudentReportsSemesterResults.FileSemester = 4)
```

Comment: You can probably do joins instead, which at least some dbms optimize better.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and desired result?

Comment: `StudentClasses.ID` is not the ID for a StudentClasses record, but for a student? Or is this a typo?

Comment: What DBMS is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join StudentClasses to vStudentReportsSemesterResults:

```
SELECT      
  sc.ClassCode,
  srsr.StudentID, 
  srsr.AssessResultsResult, 
  srsr.AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2, 
  srsr.FileSemester, 
  srsr.FileYear,
  srsr.ClassLearningAreaCode, 
  srsr.AssessmentCode, 
  srsr.StudentNameInternal
FROM vStudentReportsSemesterResults srsr
JOIN StudentClasses sc 
  ON  sc.ID = srsr.StudentID
  AND sc.FileSemester = 1
  AND sc.FileYear = srsr.FileYear + 1
  AND EXISTS
  (
    select *
    from SubjectClasses subc
    where subc.FileYear = sc.FileYear 
      and subc.ClassCode = sc.ClassCode
      and subc.FileSemester = sc.FileSemester  
      and subc.FileType = 'A'  
      and subc.ClassCampus = 'S' 
  )
WHERE srsr.ClassLearningAreaCode in ('ENG', 'MAT', 'SCI') 
  AND srsr.AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 in ('Grade', 'Level')
  AND srsr.AssessResultsResult <> ''
  AND srsr.FileYear = 2016
  AND srsr.FileSemester = 4;
```

Comment: Perfect. this works beautifully. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is more readable:

```
SELECT      
    ClassCode,
    StudentID, 
    AssessResultsResult, 
    AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2, 
    ClassLearningAreaCode, 
    AssessmentCode, 
    StudentNameInternal,
    lr.FileYear,
    lr.FileSemester, 
    tr.FileYear, 
    tr.FileSemester, 
    tr.FileType, 
    tr.ClassCampus 
FROM        
    vStudentReportsSemesterResults lr
inner join (
        select ID, sc.ClassCode, sc.FileYear, sc.filesemester, sbjc.FileType, sbjc.ClassCampus
        from StudentClasses sc
        INNER JOIN SubjectClasses sbjc ON SC.classcode = sbjc.ClassCode and sc.FileSemester=sbjc.FileSemester and sc.FileYear=sbjc.FileYear
    ) tr on lr.StudentID = tr.ID 
    and lr.FileYear = tr.FileYear - 1
WHERE      
    ClassLearningAreaCode IN ('ENG', 'MAT', 'SCI') 
    AND AssessAreaHdgAbbrev2 IN ('Grade', 'Level') 
    AND (AssessResultsResult <> '') 
    AND lr.FileYear = 2016
    AND lr.FileSemester = 4
    and tr.FileSemester = 1 
    and tr.FileType = 'A' 
    and tr.ClassCampus = 'S' 
ORDER BY 2,1,5
```

In `SELECT` section I have added some fields to better understand result.
In `WHERE` clause you can control how to filter comparision.

Put some indexes on join and filter columns and the query will run fast